P(max(x,y) < a) = P(x < a) P(y <a) yielding incorrect solution?
I was working on the below problem which, along with variants of it, has been asked multiple times on this site (here is one such example), but I'm unable to figure out why my approach is incorrect despite the other answers.
Alice and Bob have fair 30 sided and 20 sided dice, respectively. Alice rolls her die one time. However, Bob can roll his die twice and keep the maximum of the two values. In the event of a tie, Bob is the winner. Find the probability Alice is the winner.
My approach:
Set random variables for Bob's two dice $B_1$ and $B_2$, Alice's dice as A. Then, Alice wins if $max(B_1, B_2) < A$.
$P(max(B_1, B_2) < A) = P(B_1, B_2 < A) = P(B_1 < A)P(B_2 < A)$ by independence of $B_1, B_2$.
Since $B_1$ and $B_2$ are identically distributed, we can say that $P(B_1 < A)P(B_2 < A) = (P(B_1 < A))^2$.
Using the law of total probability, I find that $P(B_1 < A) = \dfrac{78}{120}$. This matches the results of the answers in this post. Then, the overall answer I get is $\dfrac{78^2}{120^2}$. I'm really struggling to figure out why this is incorrect, any hints or answers would be appreciated.

They aren't independent events.  Knowing that $B_1<A$ is evidence that $A$ is large which, in turn, suggests that $B_2<A$ as well.

@lulu thank you. Maybe I'm misinterpreting the question - I thought it was saying that Bob rolls both dice at the exact same time and simply takes the maximum, which I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) implies independence. Are you saying that instead, Bob rolls one dice, compares it to Alice's, and rolls a second?

Given three independent random variables $X,Y,Z$, the events ${X<Z}$ and ${Y<Z}$ need not be independent. Loosely speaking: these are the events ${X-Z<0}$ and ${Y-Z<0}$ and since $Z$ appears on both sides you can't use the theorem that says that measurable functions of independent random variables are independent if they take different variables as arguments.

@mk0219   None of that matters, since Bob's "comparison" doesn't alter the outcome of the die.  And, yes, the value of $B_2$ is independent of the value of $B_1$ but that's not what you are claiming.  You are claiming that the event "$B_1<A$" is independent of the event "$B_2<A$" and that is simply false.  In my posted solution I describe a more extreme variant of the problem which makes the dependence obvious.

@SassatelliGiulio Thank you, so in general, you can only claim independence of $X<Z$ and $Y<Z$ using your example if Z is some constant, as opposed to a random variable?

@mk0219 That's one case where it works. I would assume there are others.

To elaborate on the comments:  these are not independent events.  If you are told that $B_1<A$ then you increase your estimate of the probability that $A$ is large, which in turn increases your estimate of $P(X_2<A)$.  For instance, knowing that $B_1<A$ is proof that $A>1$ which already improves the chance that $B_2<A$.
To illustrate the problem, consider an extreme case.  Say $B's$ die is only two sided, with faces $2,3$ (equally probable).   Similarly, suppose that $A's$ die can only come up $1$ or $4$ with equal chance.  As in your problem, suppose that $B$ can take the max of two throws and that $A$ only gets one.  In that case, knowing that $B_1<A$ is proof that $A=4$, and hence proves that $B_2<A$ as well.    Thus, in this version, $P(\max (B_1,B_2)<A)=P(A=4)=\frac 12$, not $\frac 14$ as your method would suggest.
